# sending mass email without work flow

Tags: email

I am still in learning process here. I want to see is there a way to send mass email to all the opportunity that has specific stage , such as close lost. I use work flow but work flow needs to be triggered and that means I have to go in every single opportunity and resave it. Can I send email like that and have or use the HTML Email Template that I have in salesforce?

Comment: In what context do you want this email to be sent? Just a one-time on demand instance to all opportunities with a given stage?

Comment: And I assume to the owners of each opportunity?

Comment: @Bri you are correct,  so each lead has email address, and then we convert them to opportunity , I want those email to be sent from specific agents "The one that created them , with their email address and all their info" . The workflow doesnt work properly, it always has a lag , and on top of that each agent has to go to the oppo that they have created and re submitted for the work flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is very confusing as to who you want this sent to and from: `I want those email to be sent from specific agents "The one that created them , with their email address and all their info"`.

But here is some Apex that will send a mass email to all owners on Closed Lost Opportunities, with some email template that you specify (it would be better practice to generalize the template to not explicitly reference an ID, but that's a digression). You can run this from the Developer Console in an Execute Anonymous window. One question, this is in production right?

```
List<Opportunity> myOpps = [SELECT StageName, Ownerid FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed Lost'];
List<Id> ownerIDs = new List<Id>();
for (Opportunity o : myOpps) {
   ownerIDs.add(o.Ownerid);
}

Messaging.MassEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
emailToSend.setTargetObjectIds(ownerIDs);
emailToSend.setSubject('Your email subject');
emailToSend.setTemplateID('The ID of your Email Template goes here, in the quotes');
Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[]{emailToSend});
```

Comment: I am sorry, the rest of the my comment didnt go through. So people call and then we create lead for them, and then conver to opportunity and we save the customers email address, I want to send these emails to all those customers .

Comment: So where are those target emails stored?

Comment: contacts object, email field ..

Comment: Do I make a Class and use your code and then make a visual force page?

Comment: No. As I said, you can execute this from an execute anonymous window from the Developer Console

Comment: The snippet I posted is sending the email to the owners of the opportunities. You will have to change the parameter of setTargetObjectIds to the appropriate ones on the Contact object

Comment: you have "emailToSend" do I write a query to get the email from contact and then pass it to that... like a list?

Comment: that would work yes! you can provide a list of ALL contacts, ALL leads, or ALL users to the setTargetObjectIds method. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_setTargetObjectIds

Comment: 'Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();  
 mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactIds); 
 mail.setTemplateId('00Xq0000000M7ra');
  mail.setsubject('note'); 
  Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[]{mail});'

This gives me error  "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.MassEmailMessage].setTargetObjectIds(Set<Id>) "

Comment: pass it a List<id> not a Set<id>

Comment: You are right , its working now . For Visual force page  I have public with sharing class AprilEmailPromo {
 public AprilEmailPromo() {
     How do I call it so it runs it?

Comment: <apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="TestClass">
 <apex:commandButton onclick="testMethod();" value="Submit" id="theButton" />
</apex:page>

Comment: How do I run the code in visual force page, it gives me error.

Comment: That's a question in itself that involves controllers and pages - I would suggest posting a new question. Before we were talking about running it in the Developer Console, and now you're asking how to run it from a VF page.

Comment: I think I found the answer '<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="TestEmail" >
 <apex:form>
  <apex:commandButton value="Send Email!" action="{!TestEmail}"/>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>'

Comment: Kind of a last question, whos is the sender of this email? who does it show that this email will be sent from.

Comment: I made this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70804/sending-mass-email-without-work-flow  if you have time have a look at it please